# Как можно зашифровать ключ AES 256 - Алгоритмом RSA 2048?

Tags: c#, rsa, aes

Публичным ключом мы шифруем, приватный расшифровываем.

Примерно как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821722/c-sharp-aes-and-rsa-file-encryption-how-to-use-iv)

Мне нужно сделать шифрование файла алгоритмом AES 256.

Ключ от AES 256 шифрануть алгоритмом RSA 2048.

Чтобы без ключа не получилось получить ключ для расшифровки файла AES 256.

Можно ли такое сделать?

Comment: Почему бы и нет :)

Comment: @tym32167, хотелось бы понять как это правильно реализовать)

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Везде есть примеры как шифровать при помощи RSA и AES.

Comment: @Zergatul, Я пробовал по разному шифровать у меня всё криво получается ( Не могу понять как реализовать правильно метод шифровки-расшифровки файла внутри метода расшифровки нужно как-то добавить дополнительный метод по расшифровки с RSA ( на этом мои полномочия всё.. Буду сам как-то пытаться, если у вас есть какая-нибудь реализация, буду благодарен )

Comment: @Rudnight Делайте все поэтапно. Сделайте сначала по отдельности шифрование-расшифровку по алгоритмом AES и RSA. Когда добьетесь нормально работы этих алгоритмов по отдельности, тогда и совмещайте в целое. (подсказка: генерировать ключ для AES-256 можно через [SHA-256](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256), получается шифрование по паролю.)

Comment: @ГеннадийП, `SHA-256` можно использовать за место [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.8)  ?

Comment: @Rudnight Для проверки алгоритма достаточно простого SHA-256, который формирует хеш в 256 бит, что достаточно для AES-256. Но для стойкого шифрования лучше применять предложенный вами PBKDF2. Но по сути, надежней применять рандомно генерируемый ключ, который изначально не знает передающая сторона, и который будет передаваться только с RSA на принимающую сторону.